# Is there a way to set Environment Variables for Azure Key vault using some API within the source code (not through cli)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

I was trying to set following env variable. But I wanted to do so with api if possible. I couldn't find anything, just wanted to make sure if I can.

AZURE_CLIENT_ID - service principal's app id
AZURE_TENANT_ID - id of the principal's Azure Active Directory tenant
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET - one of the service principal's client secrets

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/quick-create-java?tabs=azure-cli - does this help ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Vineesh Vijayan, you can use the Azure key vault which lets you retrieve key-value pairs. After creating the key vault resource, you can add your environment variables by [Adding secret to Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-portal#add-a-secret-to-key-vault). Make sure you add the dependencies in `pom.xml`.

And now you can retrieve the stored keys after [Authenticating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/quick-create-java?tabs=azure-cli#authenticate-and-create-a-client) your key vault using the below line.

```
KeyVaultKey retrievedKey = keyClient.getKey(keyName);
```

In Case you trying to [Get Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/get-secret/get-secret) using rest API, you can use

```
GET {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secret-name}/{secret-version}?api-version=7.3
```

**REFERENCES:**
[Azure Key Vault Secret client library for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/security-keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-java-stable#create-a-secret)